# Difference between Daas and EAI

Tags: soa, eai

What is the difference between Daas Data as Service and EAI Enterprise Application Integration ?
I understand that EAI is a framework designed to overcome the complexities of Enterprise Software integration (between ERP, SCM, CRM etc..) using ESB Enterprise Service Bus, 
Would like to know where DAAS fits in the picture ?
Would also like to understand the difference between EAI and SOA

Answer (score 2):

[Data as a Service (DaaS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_as_a_service) gives access to data or content collected and provided by some external service provider. Examples include post area codes, geospatial data, customer address data, market prices, economic trends, exchange rates, stock quotes and bank codes.

[Enterprise Application Integration (EAI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_application_integration) is a general term which describes that applications in a (big) company are connected via a centralized facility rather than via a variety of proprietary point-to-point interfaces. To access a DaaS service, an application could use an EAI platform.

Applications can benefit from standardized EAI integration functions (connectivity, routing, data transformation, logging, monitoring, security, error handling ...) and do not have to implement these in themselves. Support and operation might also be more economic compared to point-to-point integration.

[SOA as Service-oriented Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) is a special architecture for integration. Rather than providing and consuming services, one could also send and receive messages or use a database as central information hub.